# Adding an object_id for a FK in a class based view from a kwargs

Tags: django, django-views, django-class-based-views

I'm writing a very simple Comment app. For a bunch of reasons, I need to write my own here instead of using a great product like Disqus.

So, I have a page and on that page, special users can make comments.

I've got everything working except adding the page id to the form submission.

I keep getting key errors when I try to use a hidden form field and form.cleaned_data.

So now I'm passing the page_id via the URL.

My urls.py

```
# Submit a comment
url(regex=r'^comment/create/(?P<page_id>\d+)/$',
    view=CommentCreate.as_view(),
    name='comment_create',
),
```

And my views.py

```
class CommentCreate(CreateView):
    success_url = reverse_lazy('comment_submitted')
    model = Comment
    template_name='learnd/comment_submitted.html'
    form_class = CommentCreateForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.user = self.request.user
        self.object.page = self.kwargs['page_id']
        self.object.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(CommentCreate, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

The error I'm getting is:

> Cannot assign "u'1'": "Comment.page" must be a "Page" instance.

And that's where I'm getting lost.

I think the problem is that kwargs is retuning the dictionary with u:1 but I can't figure out how to access just the 1 to pass to my view.

Any help is welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look up the `Page` object before assigning it:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    page = get_object_or_404(Page, pk=self.kwargs.get('page_id'))

    self.object = form.save(commit=False)
    self.object.user = self.request.user
    self.object.page = page
    self.object.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

Alternatively you could do `self.object.page_id = self.kwargs['page_id']` but you run the risk of the passed in `page_id` not being a valid `Page` and the `object.save()` will throw an exception.

Comment: fo my own understanding, kwargs.get('name_of_dict') will get the VALUE of that dict. Is that correct? Thanks so much!

Comment: Correct. You can also supply an optional default value so that if `.get()` does not find the key it will return the default value instead of a KeyError exception. `self.kwargs.get('page_id', 1)`